# Hiding checkbox with CSS

Tags: html, css, checkbox, display

I am new to html and css and i am working on a project where i want to use custom check boxes. 
I am trying to hide a check-box with an image via css. I dont want to re-write the html if i dont have to. Ive got my image to cover the check box using (display:none; )but this has also disabled my check box. Is there a way to make my check-box usable without displaying?

```
    input[type='checkbox'] 
    {
    display: none;
    }

    input[type='checkbox'] + label
    {
    background: url('/Pictures/checkbox_unchecked.jpg')no-repeat;
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    background-size: 100%;
    display:inline-block;
    padding: 0 0 0 0px;
    }

    input[type='checkbox']:checked + label
    {
    background: url('Pictures/checkbox_checked.jpg') no-repeat;
    height: 50px;
    width: 200px;
    background-size: 100%;
    display:inline-block;
    padding: 0 0 0 0px;
    }
```

Comment: Make it transparent with `opacity: 0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the opacity of the checkbox to 0. This still makes it clickable.

Example (click inside the black rectangle):

```css
#checkbox {
  opacity: 0;
}
#container {
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 20px;;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" onclick="alert('hello')"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Changing the opacity and then moving the checkbox worked great. Thank you!

Comment: I used this and it works perfectly but I have my div with overflow: scroll and this disables the scroll functionality. Any idea why?

Comment: @Naomi I don't know why that would happen. This shouldn't affect the scroll in any way.

Answer (score 2):

```css
label input {
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

label span.y {
  display: none;
}

label span.n {
  display: inline;
}

label input:checked ~span.y {
  display: inline;
}

label input:checked ~span.n {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" value="1">
  <span class="y">Checked!</span>
  <span class="n">Click me!</span>
</label>
```

Just change `span.y` and `span.n.` to your elements (images or something else).

Answer (score 1):

```css
input[type='checkbox'] {
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
input[type='checkbox'] + label {
  background: url('http://lorempixel.com/30/30/') no-repeat;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  background-size: cover;
  display: inline-block;
}
input[type='checkbox']:checked + label {
  background: url('http://lorempixel.com/50/200/') no-repeat;
  height: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  background-size: cover;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="check" />
<label for="check"></label>
```